# Local copy of WordPress site duplicates url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path

I am trying to make a local copy of a WordPress site. After downloading the files I change the site url to localhost in wp_option's table, at rows siteurl and home.

[image]

After that the problems begins.

The path start to duplicate the url. For example, if I try to login, instead of open the `localhost/wp-admin url`, I get `http://localhost/wp-admin/localhost/wp-login.php`.

The 'localhost' part is repeating itself at url, so all my links are broking, as you can see below.

[image]

Also, if I try to open the homepage in localhost I keep being redirect to the original site.

I already tried to change the url altering the wp-config file and the result is the same.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you modified the `.htaccess`? Where are the `wordpress files` located - which directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**METHOD-1**

You need to add `http://` and your project name.

[image]

---

**METHOD-2**

Define below code in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/digital_test');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/digital_test');
```

---

**METHOD-3**

Put below code in your current theme `functions.php`

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://localhost/digital_test');
update_option('home','http://localhost/digital_test');
?>
```

> **Important!** Do not leave those lines in the functions.php file. Remove them after the site is up and running again.

---

> **NOTE:** All settings should include the `http://` part and should not have a slash `"/"` at the end.

Comment: I have done method 1 and that looks correct but I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Eoin All settings should include the `http://` part and should not have a slash `"/"` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you need to mention your default paths inside wp-config.php and theme's functions.php

wp-config.php - place at the top

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');
```

functions.php - place at the top

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://localhost' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://localhost' );
```